# Why Storyboards are preferred on Nib. iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, nib

I am developing apps for iOS and never used storyboard. But most of the people prefer them over nib. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboard is an improvement on the NIBs concept and is the latest addition to the iOS UI toolkit. Storyboards helps you visually see the flow of your application, how the contents are represented in each layout (screens) and the transitions between them. It also helps you to manage the way controllers like View Controllers, Nav Controllers, TabBar Controllers etc communicate and respond to each other.